# Unable to get result through stored procedure for dataset in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetPatientSearchResultFromLocation(@Searchvalue varchar(100))
AS
   SELECT    
      RegNo, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, EmailId, FrCityId, Location, MobileNo
   FROM         
      PatientsReg
   WHERE     
      (Location LIKE '@Searchvalue%');
```

Here if I run just the SQL query it gives me the appropriate output but when I use it in this procedure it does not return any value but just plain table structure.

My c# code is as follows:

```
public DataTable GetPatientDetailsFromLocation(string Searchvalue)
{
        command = new SqlCommand("GetPatientSearchResultFromLocation", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Searchvalue", Searchvalue);
        command.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters;
        adp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        connection.Open();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        connection.Close();
         return ds.Tables[0];
}
```

there are no exception / errors but no values too.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What **RDBMS** are you using? You've tagged your question with `plsql` which is PL/SQL found in Oracle - but the code looks a lot like Microsoft **SQL Server** ....

Comment: Probably you should update your tags also. PL/SQL is Oracle SQL Language, but you use classes for SQLServer

Comment: Hmm ya Am using sql server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
(Location LIKE '@Searchvalue%');
```

to:

```
(Location LIKE @Searchvalue + '%');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1210760/iswanto-san That Just Worked like a miracle Iswanto San. But I dont understand why is such a difference present when both products belong to microsoft i.e. the sql server and the procedures as well?

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the LIKE clause

```
  (Location LIKE '@Searchvalue%');
```

should be

```
  (Location LIKE @Searchvalue);
```

without the single quotes, while the '%' wild card should be added to the parameter value directly in C# code.

```
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Searchvalue", Searchvalue + "%");
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be @Searchvalue+'%' ?

Comment: I guess the error persisted because I copy pasted the query directly from the sql server because it ran fine over there.

Comment: Thankyou Very much for the help !! Impressive!! But shouldn't the query rendering engines work same in both?